# PHP / MySQL - update table data with session data

Tags: php, mysql, session

**How to update table data with data stored in session?**

I have following code but it is not working(INSERTING INTO DB not working exactly). Please not that this is just part of the code. Session value are being saved correctly. I have a problem with saving them though.

If I have made silly mistake - apologies - I'm newby.

```
    $loggedTime = $_SESSION['loggedtime'];
    $thisUser = $_SESSION['usr'];

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE 'admin' SET dt = $loggedTime WHERE $thisuser");
    if($result) {
         echo "success"; 
    } else { 
        echo "no success"; 
    }
```

Comment: please enlighten us what is `NOT WORKING`

Comment: Never output a fixed string while debugging data base problems, it's utterly useless. Always use `mysql_error()` to tell you exactly WHY a query failed.

Comment: @Marc - can you give ma an example please? Currently my statement is  returning  'no success' so something is wrong.

Comment: `$res = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` is the quickest/easiest form.

Comment: I did: `echo mysql_error()."<br />";` and has returned `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:45:32 WHERE usr =' at line 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"UPDATE `admin` SET `dt` = '$loggedTime' WHERE user = '$thisUser'"
```

Don't use single quotes around column/table names. Single/double quotes indicate string literals. Use back ticks around table/column names, if you have to (i.e. reserved word). Also, have a look at [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Furthermore, you need a column in the `where` clause.

Comment: after update I'm getting an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:45:32 WHERE usr =' at line 1`

Comment: @NewUSer typo in variable name. Updated it.

Comment: @cularis - updated, but still an error full code here http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/GSAk6/

Comment: You are not using the query provided in the answer. Single quotes around strings are missing.

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE 'admin'`

replace the single quote

```
UPDATE admin SET ...
```

Understand lots of people tend to use back-tick to quote the table, column name 
... i don't think is necessary

just take a look on the mysql docs
*THEY never do that*

Comment: I guess it started with phpMyAdmin adding back ticks to every object name, because people tend to use reserved words for tables and columns (desc as a shortcut for description for example). So everybody started putting back ticks around them.

Comment: rule number one, don't use reserved words (is reserved) for table name, column name :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to explicitly name the column in your `WHERE` clause and surround variables with single quotes.

```
"UPDATE `admin` SET dt = '$loggedTime' WHERE user = '$thisuser'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres a problem with your SQL query.

```
UPDATE 'admin' SET dt = $loggedTime WHERE $thisuser
```

The where clause isn't specifying any condition try:

```
UPDATE 'admin' SET dt = '$loggedTime' WHERE userField = $thisuser
```

replacing 'userField' with a relavent field name that you would like to condition for.

Comment: ^ this. and you might want to add curly brackets when you insert variables. ie. `"UPDATE admin SET dt = {$loggedTime} WHERE someField  = {$thisUser}"` you know, just so we cool.